Why is my keyboard acting weird with shift input not being detected with Windows 11?
My keyboard is suddenly acting weird. I am using Windows 11.
Certain combinations stopped working when using Shift, but then resolve when I use the other key.
For example, if I pressed left-Shift a then nothing happened. I tried dozens of times but once I pressed right-Shift a then the capital “A” did come and suddenly left-Shift worked as well.
Same for the “@” sign (Shift+2) but in reverse, right-Shift did not work until I first did a left-Shift.
What can explain such odd behavior?
The keyboard is about 2 months old, the PC less than a year.

Hmmm, that is peculiar behaviour. A keyboard driver issue would be my best guess. Update them and see what happens.

Old keyboard, worn cable, oxidized connectors or internal parts (key switches?). Maybe even partly malfunctioning circuitry inside.
Best way to remedy: Get a new keyboard.

The keyboard is less than 2 months old

You could have told that in the Q. sigh how about the computer / MB.

It is possible that the wrong keyboard language is installed.
Please click on the Windows Key and the S key at the same time.
Type word language in the search then open the page.
Make sure all the settings for language, region, and region format for your location.
If it not correct, change the settings to the correct ones.
Then restart the computer.
